Reason for utilizing Fibonacci sequences in design
When determining the ratio of the grid layout or choosing the sizes of texts and Web UI elements, it is common practice to choose a sequence of numbers from the Fibonacci sequence.
Aside from the aesthetic side, is there any pragmatic reason for choosing numbers from a Fibonacci sequence?
I think one reason would be the ease of dividing the spaces asymmetrically (e.g., 5+8=13 units can be divided into 5 and 8 units). However, I can't verify whether my guess is correct or not.
